# Are there any SciFi/Fantasy novels with a Whale Civilization at the core?

Tags: story-identification, novel, sentience

I was reading something with my kids about how humpback whales could probably communicate across an entire ocean before human noise pollution was introduced.  This plus the theorized intelligence of whales makes me think there could be an awesome whale-based fantasy/sci-fi series.  Is there one?

I can think of these examples of sapient/sentient whales:

- In 'Star Trek 4: The Voyage Home' the Earth was nearly destroyed because an alien intelligence could no longer communicate with (implicitly sentient) humpbacks, since they had gone extinct
- In the novel 'Whale Rider' (and to some extent the movie), right whales are somewhat intelligent and have legends
- The TV Show 'Seaquest' featured an intelligent dolphin IIRC

Are there other examples, hopefully with whales playing a central role?

Comment: This is a great question. Just not for this site as it is a list question.

Comment: @DampeS8N - any ideas on what site would it be good for?

Comment: Our chat room would be a great place to ask about whale stories. As would any of a number of forums. You could also start a whale story list on wikipedia. That's kind of why we don't cover it, the wiki format is way way better for lists.

Comment: I wish I could appeal this question -- lots more story identification posts these days... I realize this isn't exactly story identification but similar.

Comment: @zipquincy the other examples are about **specific** things, you question is asking for a general list, which is not allowed here.

Comment: @zipquincy List questions like this are still off-topic, but DampeS8N's suggestion of asking in chat is a good idea.

Comment: @Keen the only thing about chat is it's so fleeting a time period that the person who might be able to answer could see it... oh well, one of the flaws of SO approach IMHO

Comment: @zipquincy That's why we have regular Recommendation events in chat.  There was one today, for example.  Usually they're pretty empty though of people seeking recommendations.  However, there's usually several people in chat idling, so you might get an answer at any time.

Comment: @Keen good tiip!

Comment: There is at least one positive answer to this question.  In David Brin's **Uplift Series** one of the books is about intelligent dolphins piloting starships.  I believe this book discussed "ongoing" efforts to uplift other cetaceans.